# Is not an enclosing class - Android

Tags: java, android

В методе onClick() вызывая активность, код выделяется красным, говоря Is not an enclosing class
Класс ScrollingActivityGroups:

```
public class ScrollingActivityGroups extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Card> groups;
    private RecyclerView rv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);


    rv = findViewById(R.id.rv_groups);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();


} //далее несколько методов
```

Класс RVAdapterGroups:
public class RVAdapterGroups extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cardView;
    TextView groupName;
    TextView groupConsist;
    ImageView groupPhoto;
    int currentCardPosition;
    Context mContext;

    CardViewHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        groupName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dish_name);
        groupConsist = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dish_consist);
        groupPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dish_photo);
        mContext = context;
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mContext instanceof ScrollingActivityGroups){
                    switch (currentCardPosition) {
                        case 0: Intent intent2 = new Intent(ScrollingActivityGroups.this, ScrollingActivitySoups.class); //выделено красным
                            Intent.startActivity(intent2);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Класс ScrollingActivitySoups абсолютно аналогичен ScrollingActivityGroups. Я использую RecylerView+CardView, и могла ли быть ошибка из-за того, что onClick() прописан в адаптере? 
Также, читая форумы, предлагают писать в выделенной строчке `Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ScrollingActivitySoups.class);`, но тогда первый параметр метода принадлежит `View.onClickListener` и метод не выполняется. Как правильнее переписать эту строчку?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin попытка обьявить, с какой активности на какую переключаться. Конструктор - Intent(context, class)

Comment: Не, прошу прощения, наврал ) Ваша констукция должна работать. AppCompatActivity наследуется же от класса Context

Comment: Какую ошибку пишет?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Сработало так:
`if(mContext instanceof ScrollingActivityGroups){
                        ScrollingActivityGroups groups = (ScrollingActivityGroups)mContext;
                        switch (currentCardPosition) {
                            case 0:
                                Intent intent2 = new Intent(groups.getApplicationContext(), ScrollingActivitySoups.class);
                                groups.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent2);
                        }
                    }`

Comment: ) Должен и ваш код работать

Comment: Ну, раз мой вариант сработал, то восстановлю его. Сейчас налетят стервятники и объяснят что к чему ))

Comment: Автор, у вас же есть доступ у контексту через 'mContext', его и используйте для создания и запуска интентов, зачем еще огород городить с приведением типов и контекстом приложения?